# Can we parse response in jmeter

Tags: javascript, html, jmeter, response

Im newbie to jmeter and Im stuck in a situation. Altough scenario is simple but like i said Im newbie to Jmeter.
I have to request a webpage.
In response I will receive an HTML file which will contain a java script code.
I have confirm some string present in that javascript code 
I know I can do this with the help of seleium webdriver and I already done it so far but I need to run this test multiple times.
and as far as JMeter goes it discard any scrip present in response. So please help me out

Answer (score 1):

JMeter will not *run* Javascript. That doesn't mean that it will ignore it.

Add a Response Assertion to your HTTP Request Sampler (right click on it, Add -> Assertions -> Response Assertion). This will let you add Strings and Assert that that String exists in the Response (NB: unlike, for instance, C++, an assertion here won't stop your test, it will only make that Sampler an error).

To use the Response Assertion, switch the Radio Button to `Contains` and click `Add` at the bottom center. In the new box that shows up in the center, add the "some string present in that javascript code."

Comment: my problem is not fully resolved mainly I was not able to tell you exact situation let me try to elaborate it once again.
we have an abc.html page on site1.com I have to load it in jmeter and this abc.html contain a "script" which in result "ping" another html file on site site2.com e.g https://site2.com/scripts/invitation.ashx?company=TestCompany 
this invitation.ashx after verify company name send a javascript widget I need to confirm that this javascript widget is "loaded" or not 
I hope i have cleared my sitation further. 
In any of case thanks a lot for the prompt responses.

Comment: So you're going to need to add another HTTP request that does the 'ping.' You'll probably need to do some sort of RegEx on the first request to feed into the second.

Answer (score 0):

First of all in your HTTP request sampler, you should select an option, 'Retrieve all embedded resources', after this jmeter will retrieve all resources like css,js,graphics etc.

Also you might want to take a look at http://jmeter-plugins.org/

This library contains some really cool plugins for jmeter testing.
You should look for some kind of Post Processors and add that to your test script. These can be used to extract some particular resources from retrieved data.

Also, one unrelated advice because you are new, Do not add Many/Any Listeners to your jmeter test plan.

Answer (score 0):

From [JMeter Project Main Page](http://jmeter.apache.org/)

> **JMeter is not a browser**
>
> JMeter is not a browser. As far as web-services and remote services are concerned, JMeter looks like a browser (or rather, multiple browsers); however JMeter does not perform all the actions supported by browsers. **In particular, JMeter does not execute the Javascript found in HTML pages.** Nor does it render the HTML pages as a browser does (it's possible to view the response as HTML etc., but the timings are not included in any samples, and only one sample in one thread is ever viewed at a time).

JMeter acts on protocol level, of your JavaScript is doing something local - you can duplicate the logic using [JSR223 Test Elements](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler)

If JavaScript is used to send a request - you can mimic the request using JMeter, JMeter doesn't execute JavaScript but it is able to record and replay JavaScript-driven requests with [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) and [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers

If you're trying to load test an application which is [AJAX-based](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) and you need to simulate the requests from real browser (i.e. asynchronous, several requests at a time triggered by opening the page, etc) - you will need to do some extra work as JMeter doesn't provide any test elements to jump over defined virtual users defined on [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) level. There are several techniques on testing AJAX applications with JMeter, see [How to Load Test AJAX/XHR Enabled Sites With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-ajaxxhr-enabled-sites-jmeter) guide for more details